# Subversion Externals: possible to combine several externals into one directory?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to combine several externals into one directory?

e.g.:

$ svn propget svn:externals calc

third-party/sounds //svn.example.com/companyA/sounds

third-party/sounds //svn.example.com/companyB/sounds

Comment: feature is marked as "invalid" by subversion team

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the second statement will take precedence over the first and you'll only get the files from companyB.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No youd need to do:

```
svn mkdir third-party third-party/sounds
svn propedit svn:externals third-party/sounds

-- propeditor --
companyA prot://url/to/companyA/sounds/
companyB prot://url/to/companyB/sounds/
-- write-close --

svn commit third-party -m "Yay Externals!"
```

Comment: this will give you two directories (companyA, companyB) not one combined dir.

Comment: Correct... i should have noted it as an alternative not necessarily a solution. Although im not sure why you would want to combine to seperate libraries into a single library with no direct scoping within the filesystem - IMO that smells bad. :-)

Comment: It was planned to build a pool of library files, so that every developer only needs one reference path to all 3rd party libs. Not too  uncommon solution, at least using delphi.